# Existence theorem for differential-difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I am examining a system of nonlinear differential-difference equations of the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x(t),k(\lfloor t\rfloor))
\end{equation}
with $f:[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and
\begin{equation}
k(\ell+1)=g(k(\ell),x(\ell)),\quad \ell\in\mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
where  $g:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. By $\lfloor t\rfloor$ we denote the largest integer smaller than or equal to $t$. Also, it is assumed that $f$ satisfies the following continuity property at the integer times:
\begin{equation}
f(\ell,x,k_1)=f(\ell,x,k_2)\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{R}^m,\ell\in\mathbb{N}
\end{equation}

I am interested in the existence (and uniqueness) of solutions for these mixed differential-difference equations. I was wondering if someone could point to some existing result in the literature or if a new theorem should be proved.

Comment: This can be formulated as an impulsive or a hybrid system. Check the book by Goebel, Sanfelice, and Teel.

Answer (score 2):

This system can be reformulated as

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x}(t)&=&f(t,x(t),y(t))\\
\dot{y}(t)&=&0
\end{array}
$$
when $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}-\mathbb{N}$ and
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
x(t_k^+)&=&x(t_k)\\
y(t_k^+)&=&g(x(t_{k-1}), y(t_{k-1}))
\end{array}
$$ where $t_k=k$.

Existence and uniqueness is immediate for the discrete-time part. Therefore, all you need to prove is that the solution of the differential equation is unique for all possible initial conditions and all possible state values given by the map $g$. Existence and uniqueness of ODEs is a well-studied problem. For instance, you may require that $f$ is globally Lipschitz with linear growth at most.